# How to print div inner html

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have aspx page and some html in div control. I am trying to print the html, after print the page i got url in the page bottom and title of the page on the uppaer side. but I want to print only div inner html. please help.

Comment: Can you paste some code please?

Comment: have you tried anything? the general approach is document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML, where divID is the id of element you're targeting.

Comment: you cant remove url from bottom and title from top on hard copy of web page programmatic because these are browser settings..

Answer (score 0):

function printPage(my_DIV) 
{

```
var headline = document.getElementById("my_DIV");



    var sStart = "<html><head>";

    var w = window.open('about:blank','printWin','width=660,height=440,scrollbars=yes');
    var wdoc = w.document;
    wdoc.open();
    wdoc.writeln(  "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">");
    wdoc.writeln(  "</head><body style=\"background-image:none;background-color:white;\">");

    wdoc.writeln(  "<div style=\"direction: "+d+"; margin: 10px\">" );


    wdoc.writeln(  "<p>" );
    wdoc.writeln(  headline.innerHTML );
    wdoc.writeln(  "</p>" );

    wdoc.writeln(  "</div>" );
    wdoc.writeln(  "</body></html>");

    wdoc.close();
    w.print();
```

}

--CALL -- printPage(div1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clean way of doing it with jQuery:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/printElement

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS with a media attribute "print" you can hide parts of the page you do not wish to print.

Here's a tutorial http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/